# How to get buildbot build properties in the email subject while using MailNotifier?

Tags: buildbot

I am trying to send custom email status notification on our buildbot system. I could not find a way to get build properties in the Email subject while using MailNotifier.

I found build object in the messageFormatter callback function parameter. But it can be used only in the body and not in subject.

I also tried using Json API by calling it from my master.cfg itself but it is not working and buildbot server goes on some kind of infinite loop. Json api if called separately works fine to query build specific data.

I am using buildbot 0.8.12 and I am new to this framework. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Per `MailNotifier`'s docstring:

```
@param messageFormatter: function taking (mode, name, build, result,
    master_status) and returning a dictionary
    containing two required keys "body" and "type",
    with a third optional key, "subject". The
    "body" key gives a string that contains the
    complete text of the message. The "type" key
    is the message type ('plain' or 'html'). The
    'html' type should be used when generating an
    HTML message.  The optional "subject" key
    gives the subject for the email.
```

So you can just add one more item to the result dictionary and you get what you want.  E.g.

```
...
return {..., 'subject': 'Abracadabra %s' % build.getProperty('my-favourite-build-property')}
```